# Android Action Bar with Search View

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to do an action bar that looks like this:

[image: ActionBar]

and I am not able to do this.

I tried to use that collapse thing described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView), but it is not exactly what i want.

- First of all SearchView isn't visible till user press search icon.. but I want It to be visible immediately after activity starts.
- Secondly after SearchView appears all other action icons disappear.. But I want them to be visible all the time.
- And it works only for android 3 and higher, I want it for android 2 and higher, so I am using ActionBarSherlock.

For example action bar in google maps looks similar to what I want.

Can somebody advise me how to achieve this?

Comment: Here is google maps action bar that I thought [google maps](http://vojtechbartos.com/mapyactionbar.png)

Comment: What you want is to add a custom view to your actionbar.
Api Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(int)

And call it like:
getActionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.mySearchbar);

Comment: Thanks!:) I did it exactly like u said.. I created layout search_bar.xml with one EditText in it..

Then I write this `actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar); actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);` into onCreate method in activity.. and it works!

So... realy thank u man!:)

Answer (score 14):

ActionbarSherlock is a great library. The latest(4.2.0) release has the method to make you search view visible when the activity starts **SearchView.setIconified(boolean);**

So if you want to make your search view always visible you should use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    //Create the search view
    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search for countries…");
    searchView.setIconified(false);

    menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_search)
            .setActionView(searchView)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);


}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you using actionbarsherlock you must to do smth like this

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 1, 1, R.string.ac_refresh ).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_navigation_refresh).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add(0, 2, 2, R.string.ac_settings).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_settings).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add(0, 3, 3, R.string.ac_favourite).setIcon(isFavouriteChannel(channel) ? R.drawable.ic_rating_important : R.drawable.ic_rating_not_important).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add(0, 4, 4,  R.string.ac_search  ).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search).setActionView(R.layout.action_search)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Take a look at setActionView(R.layout.action_search) - this is your text view in xml file. If you want your other action icons apeear always you should use `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS`